# How can I avoid advancing a loop until a condition is met?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I wrote the following program:

```
numb= ["First", "Second", "Third"]
players=[]
n = ''
score=[]

for i in numb:
    print("Type the score of the name of the", i, "player:")
    answer = n = str(input(' '))
    players.append(d)

for a in players:
    for b in numb:
        a = int(input("Type the", b, "score of", a))
        if a!=0:
            score.append(a)
        else:
```

I want to avoid advancing the inner loop `for b in numb:` as long as a is 0. 
For example: if the first score is 0, the program will print again *"Type the first score..."*.

Answer (score 2):

I think that that is it what you want:

```
for a in players:
   for b in numb:
       done = False
       while not done:
           a = int(input(f"Type the {b} score of {a}"))
           if a :
               score.append(a)
               done = True
```

`done` starts False, and when it is True while breaks and goes to next list element

off topic: I add some PEP8 to your code, hope you enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

In python >= 3.8 you could use the newly added [Walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html?highlight=walrus%20operator):

```
for a in players:
    for b in numb:
        while (a := int(input(f"Type the {b} score of {a}")) == 0:
            pass
        score.append(a)
```